# how to pause parent activity until child activity finish

Tags: android, android-intent

I have some files which i want to send through the `Bluetooth`. 
Here is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
        String multifile[] = {"/sdcard/file1.txt", "/sdcard/file2.txt", "/sdcard/file3.txt"};
        int len = multifile.length;
        Intent Int = new Intent();

        Int.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
        Int.setType("*/*");

        String packageName = null;
        String className = null;
        boolean found = false;
        PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
        List appsList = pm.queryIntentActivities( Int, 0);

        ArrayList<ResolveInfo> list = (ArrayList<ResolveInfo>) pm.queryIntentActivities(Int, PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);
        for(ResolveInfo info: list) {
            packageName = info.activityInfo.packageName;

            if( packageName.equals("com.android.bluetooth")) {
                className = info.activityInfo.name;
                found = true;
                break;// found
            }
        }

        if (!found) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "not foud bluetooth",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // exit
        }

        Int.setClassName(packageName, className);

        for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
            File file=new File(multifile[i]);
            uris.add(Uri.fromFile(file));
        }

        Int.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
        startActivity(Int);
        onStop(); //stop here till all file have been sent 
        //delete all files which is to be send    
    }
}
```

all three files have been sent but the problem is execution of `Mainactivity` continue 
before `Intent Int` is finished due that all files are delete before sending the files
Please help how to stop execution of `Mainactivity` until Int send all files

Answer (score 1):

If your "mainactivity" is starting the child, have it start it using `startActivityForResult()` and have it not take further action (not delete files) until the child result is available and indicates that it finished without errors.

If there isn't this parent/child relationship, there are several options but one easy one is have the lower level activity broadcast a message that the higher level activity receives and only does the follow-up work after it has been received.

Answer (score 0):

You can use startActivityForResult. The parent activity will wait for a callback from the called activity.

e.g.

```
Intent i = new Intent(this,CalledActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, requestCode);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
Log.d("CheckStartActivity","onActivityResult and resultCode = "+resultCode);
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
if(resultCode==1){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Pass", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Still I can not figure out how to use startActivityforResult with Int.setClassName(packageName, className);

Comment: @JOHNCENA you are currently starting the activity with `startActivity(Int)`. _Instead_ of that, start it with `startActivityForResult(Int, _requestCode_);` AND create an `onActivityResult()` method. Your _requestCode_ (value is of your choice, doesn't matter elsewhere) will be fed back to `onActivityResult()` along with the result the child provided (using `setResult()`).

Comment: But how to pause the parent activity because execution of parent activity is continue after startactivityforresult that the main problem please help

Answer (score 0):

From your `MainActivity` call the `ChildActivity` by using `startActivityForResult()`. So the main activity will wait until the child activity finish its process. When the child activity get finished use `setResult()` to indicate the MainActivity that the process is completed.

Receive the result in `onActivityResult()` and then do what ever you want from the `MainActivity`.